# Pass asynchronously fetched data to another class

Tags: xcode, swift, model-view-controller, asynchronous

I'm designing an iOS App using Swift. I have a View Controller, `DisplayBrand` that's displaying data fetched from a backend. I have made another class, `FetchAndParseBrand`, for fetching and parsing data from the backend.

The view controller is calling a method, `getBrand`, in the fetching class. This method then revieces data asynchronously from the backend.

**How do I return the received data to the View Controller?** I guess there are multiple ways of solving this problem, do you have any suggestion for the best practice?

Here is some code for context:

**DisplayBrand**

```
class DisplayBrand: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var brand = Brand()
    FetchAndParseBrand().getBrand()
    self.updateUI()
    }   
...
}
```

**FetchAndParseBrand:**

```
class FetchAndParseBrand: NSObject {

// Fetches one brand on static url
func getBrand() -> Brand{

        let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value)
        var jsonError: NSError?
        var brand = Brand()

        if let url = NSURL(string: "http://backend.com/api/brand")
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0))
                {
                    // simulate long load delay
                    println("going to sleep")
                    sleep(2)     

                    if let brandData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                            {
                                if let jsonBrand = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(brandData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary {
                                    if let newName = jsonBrand.valueForKey("Name") as? String {
                                        brand.name = newName
                                    }
                                    if let newGender = jsonBrand.valueForKey("Gender") as? Int {
                                        if newGender == 0 {brand.gender = "male"}
                                        else if newGender == 1 {brand.gender = "female"}
                                    }
                                    if let newId = jsonBrand.valueForKey("Id") as? Int {
                                        brand.id = newId
                                    }
                                    brand.printBrand()
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
        return brand
    } 
}
```

**Brand**

```
class Brand: NSObject {

var id: Int?
var name: String?
var image: UIImage?
var gender: String?

func printBrand() {
    if id != nil { println("ID:\t\t\(self.id!)") }
    if name != nil { println("Name:\t\(self.name!)") }
    if image != nil { println("Image:\t\(self.image?.description)") }
    if gender != nil { println("Gender:\t\(self.gender!)") }
    }
}
```

Comment: The two common solutions for this problem are delegation (using delegates and protocols) and notifications (using `NSNotification`). A third common solution is to pass around completion handlers.

Comment: So letting `FetchAndParseBrand` delegate `getBrand` to `DisplayBrand` ?
What would you suggest as best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a completion handler for this, this will return the variable when it is read:

```
class FetchAndParseBrand: NSObject {
    class func getBrand(completion: (brand: Brand) -> ()) {

        let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value)
        var jsonError: NSError?
        var brand = Brand()

        if let url = NSURL(string: "http://backend.com/api/brand")
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0))
                {
                    // simulate long load delay
                    println("going to sleep")
                    sleep(2)

                    if let brandData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                        {
                            if let jsonBrand = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(brandData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary {
                                if let newName = jsonBrand.valueForKey("Name") as? String {
                                    brand.name = newName
                                }
                                if let newGender = jsonBrand.valueForKey("Gender") as? Int {
                                    if newGender == 0 {brand.gender = "male"}
                                    else if newGender == 1 {brand.gender = "female"}
                                }
                                if let newId = jsonBrand.valueForKey("Id") as? Int {
                                    brand.id = newId
                                }
                                completion(brand: brand)
                                brand.printBrand()
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function like so:

```
FetchAndParseBrand.getBrand { (brand) -> () in
    println(brand)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways. with callback function and delegates. you can also use singleton if you will call back only to a specific view controller:

```
class DisplayBrand: UIViewController {
    static var sharedInstance :DisplayBrand?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DisplayBrand.sharedInstance = self;

}
```

.
.
.

```
//on async over:
displayBrand.sharedInstance?.someFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a major issue in your code:

`FetchAndParseBrand.getBrand()` is supposed to be a class method and has no parameter

The easiest way to get a asynchronous callback is a closure

Try this

**Class DisplayBrand**

```
class DisplayBrand: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    FetchAndParseBrand.getBrand() { (brand) -> () in
      // do something with variable brand
      self.updateUI() }
  }

 ...
}
```

**Class FetchAndParseBrand**

```
class FetchAndParseBrand: NSObject {

  // Fetches one brand on static url
  class func getBrand(completion: (Brand)->()) {

    let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value)
    var jsonError: NSError?
    var brand = Brand()

    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://backend.com/api/brand")
    {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0))
        {
          // simulate long load delay
          println("going to sleep")
          sleep(2)

          if let brandData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
          {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
              {
                if let jsonBrand = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(brandData, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as? NSDictionary {
                  if let newName = jsonBrand.objectForKey("Name") as? String {
                    brand.name = newName
                  }
                  if let newGender = jsonBrand.objectForKey("Gender") as? Int {
                    if newGender == 0 {brand.gender = "male"}
                    else if newGender == 1 {brand.gender = "female"}
                  }
                  if let newId = jsonBrand.objectForKey("Id") as? Int {
                    brand.id = newId
                  }
                  brand.printBrand()
                  completion(brand)
                }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Side note: `valueForKey` is a key value coding method. The standard method to get a value from a dictionary by key is `objectForKey` or use subscripting